# How to write postrotate script for logrotate to copy last part of log files to another

Tags: logrotate

So I am trying to rotate my logs using logrotate. I currently am using copytruncate but it is not catching all of my data when it rotates logs. I can see that approx. the lat 50 lines of data are getting lost which is expected from the copy truncate spec.

I have done some research and some people have suggested that I use postrotate script and write a script in it that would copy the last part of my log file and paste it into the newly generated file when it rotates so that I don't lose any data (although I may have duplicates which is fine).
Does anyone know how I can do that? I am new to any sort of script writing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) the post rotate is implemented this way for example :

```
 /var/log/mylogfile{
           rotate 5
           weekly
           postrotate
                                     /sbin/killall -HUP syslogd
           endscript
       }
```

In this example the `/sbin/killall -HUP syslogd` command will be executed after the log file is rotated :

> **postrotate/endscript** : The  lines  between postrotate and endscript (both of which must
>                 appear on lines by themselves) are executed after the  log  file
>                 is  rotated.  These  directives  may only appear inside of a log
>                 file definition.  See prerotate as well.

According to the this you should write a script that will copy some line from your log file to the newly created file.

Your final script will look like this :

```
/var/log/mylogfile {
               rotate 5
               weekly
               postrotate
                                         tail -n 50 mylogfile >> mylogfile0
               endscript
           }
```

In the script I copy the last 50 lines from mylogfile which is the originate log file to mylogfile0 which is the newly created file.